# mod_rewrite restrict access to all files except index + rewrite links correctly

Tags: perl, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know how to restrict acces to all files except index.pl, search.pl, .js and .css files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(?!(index|search)\.pl).+$ - [F,NC]
```

Also I know how to rewrite links:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/((edit|delete))/([0-9]+)$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/((add)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1 [L]
```

How I can use BOTH this functions (allow only few files + rewrite links).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server configuration and belongs on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rewrites before the deny rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(edit|delete|info)/([0-9]+)$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(add)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(index|search)\.pl).+$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: I edited your answer. Now workable verison - answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103974/mod-rewrite-how-to-rewrite-links-correctly.Thank you.