# mod_rewrite, how to rewrite links correctly

Tags: php, perl, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite links on my site.
Possible links before rewrite and what I want to see after rewrite:
`/index.pl?mode=users&action=add` - `/users/add/`
`/index.pl?mode=streets&action=edit&id=7` - `/streets/edit/7`
`/index.pl?mode=users&action=info&id=7` - `/users/info/7`
etc

.htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/((edit|delete|info))/([0-9]+)$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/((add))/?$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1 [L]
```

`/users/add/` or `/street/add/` are working properly, but...
Problems:
`/users/edit/xx` - I can't accept ID in perl script. Why? 
`/users/info/xx` - I can't even get to info section `/?mode=users&action=info&id=7` page (it have to show blank table with wrong ID

Btw... My site has 'switch' structure. I mean if mode is users, then it load "users.pl", if mode=streets loading "streets.pl", etc. About 2nd problem - sure I have info section at users.pl! And link `/?mode=users&action=info&id=7` work perfect.

p.s.: added php-tag because it is not 'perl' problem , but php is equal to perl, so php-followers can help me too

p.p.s.: sry for my not very good english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many parentheses, which makes your backreferences off-by-one:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(edit|delete|info)/([0-9]+)$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(add)/?$ index.pl?mode=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Those two rules had too many parentheses around the `((edit|delete|info))` and `((add))` (though the "add" isn't affected because $2 correctly backreferences it).

Comment: True. You are right. Totaly forgot about it. 1 more question: I have info section only in users.pl script, streets and others don't have it. Is it possible to access info only with users: `/users/info/7` and restrict for others: `/streets/info/7` - mustn't work. Anyway, maybe you can somehow improve these expressions? @Jon Lin

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You're going to need to create a separate rule specifically for the `^users/info/([0-9]+)$` pattern and remove the "info" from the more general rule.

Comment: Look, if I input not correct link (which doesn't match rules) I will get 403, right? Is it possible to redirect browser to main page? Or maybe it is better to create 403 error page and redirect browser to this page? @Jon Lin

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it's up to you, if you want to redirect to the main page, you need to change the `F` to `R`. But honestly, what's wrong with just returning a 404 Not Found? That's sort of the purpose of that response code, the URL doesn't exist.